# paper dialog with paper input closes on input

Tags: polymer, paper-elements

I have a `paper-dialog` and in this dialog I have a `paper-input` with some pre-defined value and when I want to change the value my dialog closes for no obvious reason.

My code:

```
<template>
  <paper-dialog entry-animation="scale-up-animation"
                exit-animation="fade-out-animation"
                id="bookDetailDialog"
                class="bookDialog"
                opened="{{opened}}">
    <paper-item style="padding-left: 11px;">
      <paper-icon-button 
            icon="icons:arrow-back" 
            on-tap="closeDialog">
      </paper-icon-button>
    </paper-item>
    <paper-item>
        <paper-input label="Author" value="{{book.author}}"></paper-input>
    </paper-item>
    ...
    <paper-item>
        <paper-checkbox checked="{{book.dedication}}">Dedication</paper-checkbox>
    </paper-item>
    <paper-button raised>Lent</paper-button>
    <paper-button raised>Sell</paper-button>
  </paper-dialog>
</template>
<script>
  Polymer({

  is: 'book-dialog',

  properties: {
    book: {
      notify: true
    },
    opened: {
      type: Boolean,
      notify: true
    }
  },

  closeDialog: function () {
    this.opened = false;
    this.book = undefined;
  }
 });
</script>
```

EDIT: This is where I use my element:

```
<dom-module id="books-list">
  <style>
    span {
      flex-basis: 100%;
      margin: auto;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <book-dialog opened="{{opened}}" book="{{selected}}"></book-dialog>
    <iron-list
        id="bookList"
        items="{{books}}"
        as="book"
        selection-enabled
        selected-item="{{selected}}">
      <template>
        <paper-item>
          <span>{{book.id}}</span>
          <span>{{book.author}}</span>
          <span>{{book.original}}</span>
          <span>{{book.language}}</span>
          <span>{{book.status}}</span>
        </paper-item>
      </template>
    </iron-list>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'books-list',

      properties: {
        books: {
          notify: true
        },
        selected: {
          notify: true,
          obsever: '_selectionChanged'
        },
        opened: {
          notify: true,
          type: Boolean
        }
      },

      observers: [
        '_selectionChanged(selected)'
      ],

      _selectionChanged: function () {
        if (this.get('selected.id') === '' 
         || this.get('selected.id') === undefined) {
        this.set('opened', false);
        } else {
          this.set('opened', true);
        }
      },

      _openAddBookDialog: function () {
        this.fire('add-book');
      }

    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

EDIT:
I think it has something to do with the `iron-list` and that the `selected` Attribute changes ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're still looking for this, however, I'll provide this for anyone who stumbles upon this question.
There is an explanation provided for a related issue concerning paper-input with paper-dialog -- [PolymerElements/paper-input Issue#263](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/issues/263#issuecomment-169310895)

Basically, you'll have to handle the click event from `paper-input`, so that it doesn't propagate to close the `paper-dialog`.
Hope that helps.